# MFC: How do you implement a context menu for CRichEditView in a CTabView tab?

Tags: mfc, contextmenu, cricheditctrl

I have a `CTabView` with one of the tabs a `CRichEditView`.  Rich text is added to the control and shows fine.  If I select text within the `CRichEditView` the toolbar edit items work fine (for example, copy highlights, and if I click on it, it copies to the clipboard).   However, I found that if I selected text and right click there is no context menu with a `CRichEditView` like there was with `CEditView`.   Searching the Internet, I found an implementation for `CRichEditView::GetContextMenu()` to try and use.   It first had an assert failure because the `CDocument` is not a rich text type, so for testing, I removed it (commented out below) and ended up with the following:

```
HMENU CMyRichView::GetContextMenu(WORD seltyp, LPOLEOBJECT lpoleobj, CHARRANGE* lpchrg)
{
  // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class
  /*
  CRichEditCntrItem* pItem = GetSelectedItem();
    if (pItem == NULL || !pItem->IsInPlaceActive())*/
    {
      CMenu menuText;
      menuText.LoadMenu(IDR_CONTEXT_EDIT_MENU);
      CMenu* pMenuPopup = menuText.GetSubMenu(0);
      menuText.RemoveMenu(0, MF_BYPOSITION);
      return pMenuPopup->Detach();
    }
}
```

Where the `IDR_CONTEXT_EDIT_MENU` is:

```
IDR_CONTEXT_EDIT_MENU MENU
BEGIN
    POPUP "edit"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "&Copy\tCtrl+C",               ID_EDIT_COPY
    END
END
```

Now when I right-click I see the context menu.  However, when I choose "copy", nothing happens.  So I mapped the `ID_EDIT_COPY` so I could set a break point to see if it was called.

```
void CMyRichView::OnEditCopy()
{
  // TODO: Add your command handler code here
    ASSERT_VALID(this);
    GetRichEditCtrl().Copy();
}
```

It's not if the context item is used, but it is if the toolbar is used.

What am I missing and doing wrong?

TIA!!

Comment: I see via spy that the command is send to the `CTabView` window.  How do I route that properly?

Comment: Yet, `ON_COMMAND(ID_EDIT_COPY, &CMyTabView::OnEditCopy)` in the message map doesn't get called?

Comment: This works for me, although my `CRichEditView` setup is not same as yours. Do you have copy/paste buttons in the toolbar and main menu? Do they work? Can you get "Paste" command to work? Is `CClipRichView` and `CMyRichView` the same thing?

Comment: I just have a copy button since this will be considered read-only for displaying data, but should be able to be copied.   I think it has to do with the message map not working.  I have a `CSplitterWnd` with 3 panes, one of which is a `CTabView`, and one of the tabs is a `CRichEditView`.   I see spy send the command to the CTabView window, but it isn't going anywhere?  Any tricks to debug this?  There must be something missing.  Again, the toolbar `copy` item works fine (message map gets it to the `CRichEditView`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the message goes to `CTabView` then add `CTabView::OnEditCopy` handler.

Otherwise, you can override `PreTranslateMessage` as shown below, this will make sure the message is sent to `CMyRichEditView::OnEditCopy`.

```
BOOL CMyRichEditView::PreTranslateMessage(MSG *msg)
{
    if(msg->message == WM_CONTEXTMENU || msg->message == WM_RBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        CMenu menu;
        menu.LoadMenu(IDR_CONTEXT_EDIT_MENU);
        int c = menu.GetMenuItemCount();
        CMenu* popup = menu.GetSubMenu(0);
        popup->TrackPopupMenu(0, msg->pt.x, msg->pt.y, this, NULL);
        return TRUE;
    }
    return CRichEditView::PreTranslateMessage(msg);
}
```

Comment: I did an `CMyTabView::OnEditCopy()` and it was never called:`ON_COMMAND(ID_EDIT_COPY, &CMyTabView::OnEditCopy)`.   But this `PreTranslateMessage()` method works!!